# regex to get two different words from a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I will be getting the string as app1(down) and app2(up) 
the words in the brackets indicate status of the app, they may be up or down depending,

now i need to use a regex to get the status of the apps like a comma seperated string

ex:ill get app1(UP) and app2(DOWN)
 required result UP,DOWN

Comment: *required result* => maybe you should include why you weren't able to get it ?

Comment: could you share what you have done?

Comment: Mandatory question: what problem is stopping you from writing your own regex/solution? One of approaches could be iterating over text using Pattern and Matcher classes to find words UP and DOWN (also case-insensitively) and store them somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy using RegEx like this:

```
\\((.*?)\\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
String x = "app1(UP) and app2(DOWN)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
String tmp = "";
while(m.find()) {
    tmp+=(m.group(1))+",";
}

System.out.println(tmp);
```

Output:

> UP,DOWN,

**Java 8: using `StringJoiner`**

```
String x = "app1(UP) and app2(DOWN)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");

while(m.find()) {
    sj.add((m.group(1)));
}

System.out.print(sj.toString());
```

Output:

> UP,DOWN

*(Last `,` is removed)*

Comment: Improvement suggestion: Since you are using StringBuilder already why do you want to concatenate strings (each time this creates new StringBuilder just to concatenate group(1) with comma so you can later add it to main StringBuilder)? Instead of `append(firstString + secondString)` is better to simply use `append(firstString).append(secondString)`. Also to avoid problem with unneeded comma at the end use `StringJoiner` (added in Java 8) with comma as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ValidateDemo
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                String input = "ill get app1(UP) and app2(DOWN)";
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("app[0-9]+\\(([A-Z]+)\\)");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(input);


                List<String> found = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (m.find())
                {
                        found.add(m.group(1));
                }

                System.out.println(found.toString());
        }
}
```

my first java script, have mercy

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
    private static final Pattern RX_MATCH_APP_STATUS = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?<name>[^(\\s]+)\\((?<status>[^(\\s]+)\\)");
    final String input = "app1(UP) or app2(down) let's have also app-3(DOWN)";
    final Matcher m = RX_MATCH_APP_STATUS.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        final String name = m.group("name");
        final String status = m.group("status");
        System.out.printf("%s:%s\n", name, status);
    }
```

This plucks from input line as many app status entries, as they really are there, and put each app name and its status into proper variable. It's then up to you, how you want to handle them (print or whatever).

Plus, this gives you advantage if there will come other states than UP and DOWN (like UNKNOWN) and this will still work.

Minus, if there are sentences in brackets prefixed with some name, that is actually not a name of an app and the content of the brackets is not an app state.

Answer (score -1):

Use this as regex and test it on http://regexr.com/
[UP]|[DOWN]

Comment: "Use this as regex" which regex? Did you mean `[UP]|[DOWN]`? If yes please test it first before posting it as answer (for now it is same as `[UPDOWN]`).

Comment: Not really the same, thou ;-) (2 matching characters in first, 1 matching character in yours).

Comment: @Cromax Is your comment reply to mine or to OP answer? If to mine then both `[UP]|[DOWN]` and `[UPDOWN]` may accept only *one* character from six given: U,P or D,O,W,N, and since we are talking here about character *sets* it can also be written simpler as `U,P,D,O,W,N`. So technically they are same (even if they are written differently).

Comment: It's reply to your comment. And you're right, I missed the `'|'` in between the original pattern.

Comment: from Qs I assumed that it will be in format of appXX(UP/DOWN) and i tested it for this scenario.

Comment: Can somebody let me know what is wrong with regex [UP]|[DOWN] which I posted ? I tested it at  http://regexr.com/